# why do i keep getting this error for my first flutter program?

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\berry.android\debug.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Do you have a debug.keystore file in that folder?  I got a similar error other day but resolved it when I moved the debug.keystore to the correct folder. Hope this helps

Comment: Be sure you write the correct path, "C:\Users\berry.android\debug.keystore". Change it to "C:\Users\berry\.android\debug.keystore"

Comment: i have a debug.keystore file in that folder but i dont have a clue as to where to move it @dogwasstar

Comment: i added the correct path but the error didnt change @RDR_Dev